# jQuery animate() goes bananas despite stop()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I got this box that expands on hover after its SVG timer is done:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/WwD5V/9/embedded/result/

But right now it goes bananas if you hover on and off many times quickly. How come placing `stop(true,true)` before each `animate()` won't fix it?

JS:

```
$('.wrapper').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.wrapper').stop(true,true).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 200);
    }, 2000);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.wrapper').stop(true,true).animate({
        width: '120px'
    }, 200);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid black;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Everything here can be done with purely css, should try that instead.

Comment: While that is true, this is just a reduced testcase of something much more elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is queue a timeout job for each mouseenter. When the timed function resolves it will stop any animation on the element, but it will not clear other timed functions.

```
$('.wrapper').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var $this = $('.wrapper');

        $this.stop(true,true).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 200);

        $this.find('.main').stop(true,true).animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 200);
    }, 2000);
});
```

So to fix, you need to check if the timeout is already set, and clear it first:

```
$('.wrapper').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    var timeoutHandle = $(this).data('timeout') || 0; 

    if (timeoutHandle > 0)
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
        var $this = $('.wrapper');

        $this.stop(true,true).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 200);

        $this.find('.main').stop(true,true).animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 200);
    }, 2000);

    $(this).data('timeout', timeoutHandle);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad to help. You might want to take a couple minutes to get familiar with underscorejs. Particularly, in this case, the `debounce` function: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce