# Mouseenter mysteriously activated when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter

I have this box which, on hover, plays a loader animation and then expands after 2 seconds:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/WwD5V/23/embedded/result/

But how come it expands immediately (with no loader animation) if I move my mouse in the following V-shaped motion?

[image]

```
var timeout;

$('.wrapper').bind('mouseenter', function () {
  if(!$('.wrapper').hasClass('expanded')) {

    $('.loader').show();

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922264/jquery-animate-goes-bananas-despite-stop

    var timeoutHandle = $(this).data('timeout') || 0;

    if (timeoutHandle > 0) clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.wrapper').animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 200);

        $('.wrapper').addClass('expanded');
    }, 2000);

    $(this).data('timeout', timeoutHandle);
  }
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.loader').hide();

    $('.wrapper').animate({
        width: '120px'
    }, 200);

    $('.wrapper').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: you need to cancel the expanding div if the mouse leaves the div **before** the 2 secs loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `mouseover`, a timeout is set. When you `mouseleave`, the timeout continues to run. It seems that you need to clear your timeout upon `mouseleave`.

I did several things to achieve this:

1) Increase the scope of the variable `timeoutHandle` at the top of the script:

```
var timeoutHandle;
```

2) Remove the `var` from your timeout definition in `mouseenter`:

```
timeoutHandle = $(this).data('timeout') || 0;
```

3) Clear the timeout on `mouseleave`:

```
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
```

[Working Example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/WwD5V/26/)

---

As you mentioned, the `expanded` class is no longer needed. I removed it in the fiddle, below.

Also, I added code to stop any current animation on `mouseleave`, in case the box is in the middle of animating. I slowed down the "expand" animation to illustrate this more clearly.

```
$('.wrapper').stop(true,false).animate({
    width: '120px'
}, 200);
```

[Working Example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/WwD5V/28/)

Comment: Great stuff, thanks again. P.S. Do tell if there's anything else you'd have done different as well. Cheers!